# How to getelementbytagname from specific asp.net web service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, cordova, getelementsbytagname

Please, I'm stuck in a little problem using getElementsByTagName command on a js file with a PhoneGap project. I'm consuming a asp.net web service that works perfectly, but I failed to get the result that the web service is returning me, and that is `string` from `<IngresarRegistroMovilResult>` tag.

This is my function that receives the web service return:

```
function processResult() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var theXML = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
        var resultadoWebService = theXML.getElementsByTagName('string')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

        var output = "Resultado: ";
        output += resultadoWebService;

        console.log("Pasamos por processResult, con var output:"+output);

        document.getElementById("resultadows").innerHTML = output;

    }
};
```

This is the specification of the web service:

```
POST /servicio.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: dondeestamifamilia.masterdevelopment.co
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <IngresarRegistroMovil xmlns="http://dondeestamifamilia.masterdevelopment.co/">
      <hashString>string</hashString>
    </IngresarRegistroMovil>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <IngresarRegistroMovilResponse xmlns="http://dondeestamifamilia.masterdevelopment.co/">
      <IngresarRegistroMovilResult>string</IngresarRegistroMovilResult>
    </IngresarRegistroMovilResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

This is the fragment corresponding to IngresarRegistroMovil method, from the wsdl:

```
<s:element name="IngresarRegistroMovil">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="hashString" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="IngresarRegistroMovilResponse">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="IngresarRegistroMovilResult" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

I've tried `theXML.getElementsByTagName('string')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;` 
but I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined`. `theXML.getElementsByTagName('string')[0];` but I get: `undefined`. `theXML.getElementsByTagName('string')[0].nodeValue;` but I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined`.

Please, your great support will be extremely valuable to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tagname is `IngresarRegistroMovilResult` not `string` which you can acces by `theXML.getElementsByTagName('IngresarRegistroMovilResult')[0].textContent` (if I made no typo)

Comment: Thanks, deamentiaemundi, for your reply. I get the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined` in line 39 of main.js. The error message says "of undefined". It says that `theXML.getElementsByTagName('IngresarRegistroMovilResult')[0]` is undefined. Why?

Comment: Mmh...no, mime-type is ok but it still might fail to return a DOM. Try to force a DOM by adding at the top : `var parser = new DOMParser();var theXML = parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseXML,"text/xml").documentElement;` And if that doesn't work...well, I'm not the man to give up *that* early ;-)

Comment: Well, @deamentiaemundi I discovered something curious: the result of consuming the web service has the value of the return variable from the web service. In other words, `theXML.innerHTML` contains `C----O`, that is the string value of `IngresarRegistroMovilResult`, flat, without tags. The error I was getting, then, is for trying to get the return value through a tagname. I will close this question. Thanks, @deamentiaemundi for your cooperation.

Comment: Ah, that was it! BTW: others may have that problem, too, so don't close this question but answer it yourself and check it as the accepted answer (if you are able to, not sure about the rules for that)

Answer (score 0):

The result of consuming the web service has the value of the return variable from the web service. In other words, theXML.innerHTML contains C----O, that is the string value of IngresarRegistroMovilResult, flat, without tags. The error I was getting, then, is for trying to get the return value through a tagname.